# How to start and stop protractor driver for each test

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I want to run my protractor tests in lambdatest cloud. to update the test name for each test I had to restart the browser for each test (it block). I tried two options

1. browser.restart() - this creates the same session again so the test name is not updated properly.
2. I used restartBrowserBetweenTests: true this restart browser as expected but an extra blank test is generated as the browser is initialized/invoked in the config.ts and from script file am passing URL using browser.get().

When I run multiple sessions in parallel the count to extra test multiplies.

Is there a way how I can manage browser initialization and quit from beforeEach and AfterEach blocks not from config file.